# Chrome - "Reopen last closed tab" not working

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I noticed that lately the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut no longer works, although [the Chrome Help Page](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179&topic=25799&rd=1) does not state that anything changed.

I got this behavior on two different computers running Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit respectively) and Chrome 18.0.1025.162.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there an explanation/fix?

Comment: Is only the hotkey not working or the whole function (it's also available in the context menu of the tab bar)?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg only the keyboard shortcut. The context menu works - didn't know that existsted :)

Comment: Make triple-sure that the hotkey isn't used globally by something else. In general, it should work. I would assume some other application captures the hotkey.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg That was it! It was Winamp's Minilyrics plugin that had a globad CTRL+SHIFT+T hotkey for 'Always on top'. Please put your comment into an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Step 1 Make sure it's the hotkey that's not working

See if the manual action still works, by right-clicking on the tab bar:
[image]

### Step 2 Make sure no other application uses your hotkey

Another application might have registered the same hotkey globally and is now capturing it before Chrome has the chance to do it.

Close some applications and see if the behavior changes.

Answer (score 3):

for whoes googling here...

Starting sept 2013 this is a real bug (not only a hotkey like in the previous response) : see http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OTQALJl0QAM

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced the same issue before and looked out for any application which uses this shortcut as well, I found Jitsi is that one.

I removed shortcut by changing the value in Tools/Options/Advanced/Keybindings/Global Shortcuts menu